# VBA - SQL Query with Cell Reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have been working on a new tool and I am needing it to run the query based on what the cells equal.

For instance,

I  have 3 cells in excel that have Data Validation. 
C4:Department
C5:Group
C6:Category

Basically if (All) is selected, run the first query, otherwise run the second. 
I need Group to run a query based on what the cell is like this:

```
If Sheets("Rollup").Range("C5").Value = "(All)" Then
Sheets("Codes").Range("B3:XFD1048576").Clear
        cn.Open SQLServerConnString
        strQuery = "Select DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC from dbo.Rollup GROUP BY DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC ORDER BY DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC"
        Set rs = cn.Execute(strQuery)
        Sheets("Codes").Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
Else Sheets("Codes").Range("B3:XFD1048576").Clear
        cn.Open SQLServerConnString
        strQuery = "Select DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC WHERE DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC = C5.Value from dbo.Rollup GROUP BY DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC ORDER BY DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC"
        Set rs = cn.Execute(strQuery)
        Sheets("Codes").Range("B3").CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
End If
```

Comment: I have read your entire question about 5 times now and I still can't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your SQL string is just a string. You have to concatenate in values to build the string you want.

```
 strQuery = "Select DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC WHERE DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC = " & Sheets("Rollup").Range("C5").Value & " from dbo.Rollup GROUP BY DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC ORDER BY DEPT_CATG_GRP_DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have SQL code embedded in a Power Query.  I have a named cell in an Excel Sheet.  I have successfully referenced that cell and used it as a filter in my power queries:

```
YAWafer = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YAWafer"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]
```

I cannot figure out how to "feed" this parameter into the embedded SQL code - ie code that is embedded into the same Power Query that uses this parameter successfully as a filter.

I have tried many different ways based on ideas I have seen in these posts, but unsuccessful.  My main motivation is to get that parameter into the embedded SQL code and use it as an upfront filter.